# Using External javascript, control Play, Stop, Pause etc. in f4player

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I search lots but i can't get any answer regarding this. I am using f4player to play mp4 video in my HTML/JavaScript file. this player work well. but i want to control play/pause/stop of f4player using JavaScript. please any one can help me.

i use
[f4player](http://gokercebeci.com/dev/f4player)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [source code for F4Player](https://github.com/gokercebeci/f4player), it would appear that it doesn't offer the ability to control the player via JavaScript.

SWF file can be programmed to allow method invocation from JavaScript by making use of the [ExternalInterface.addCallback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) method.  You could quite easily modify the source code of the player to register the required JavaScript hooks:

```
// Create an instance of the F4Player - ensure you don't pass an initial stream.
var player : Player = new Player(null);

// Register some ExternalInterface callback to allow control from the JavaScript
ExternalInterface.addCallback("play", player.Play);

// Initialize the skin in the usual fashion
skin.initialization(
    player,
    stage.stageWidth
    // ...etc.
);
```

Having said all this, you may be better served by a more complete video player solution such as the one found in [video.js](http://videojs.com/).

Comment: thanks for replying but i want to play mp4 video in firebox which think is not possible using http://videojs.com/

Comment: Pretty sure it would be; Flash can natively play MP4 video and F4Video is just a simple wrapper around the Flash video playback controls.

Comment: Hey it works nice. but i use that video tag dynamic in JavaScript so how can i right controls in javascript `<video controls data-setup="{}"> </video>`   i use this thing like `_video.controls = "data-setup={}";` but not works

Comment: I suggest you search StackOverflow for video.js related questions or read the video.js docs?